# Ajustar tamaño de imagen en CSS

Tags: css, web

Al descargar un imagen para utilizarla como fondo en un sitio web, me he percatado que sus dimensiones son elevadas y al visualizar el navegador, este muestra solo una parte de la imagen. ¿Cómo puedes "alejar" la imagen para que se pueda apreciar completa? Intenté modificar `height` y `width` pero no realizó lo que buscaba.

Lo que realicé es lo siguiente:

```
body {
    background-image: url(landscape.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar a establecer un max-width y un max-height al 100%, de tal forma que no sobrepasará los límites propios del navegador. Te adjunto un ejemplo, en el que se lo aplico a la clase de la imagen:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}
```

Y si quisieras añadir un ancho máximo fijo de la imagen, por ejemplo, simplemente colócalo dentro de un contenedor:

```
<div style="max-width:500px;">
   <img src="..." />
</div>
```